# Is their an equivalent to file:serialize-binary to store data in exist-db

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have an a web service running on the same machine as exist-db which consumes PDF (from the database as base64) and returns PNG (as base64) using httpclient.

A simple example Xquery would be:

```
xquery version "3.0";
let $testdata := util:binary-doc('/db/data/Customers/assets/logo.pdf')
let $url := "http://localhost:4802/Pdf2Img.aspx" 
let $headers := <headers></headers>
let $b64response := httpclient:post(xs:anyURI($url),$testdata,false(),$headers)/httpclient:body/text()
return
file:serialize-binary($b64response,'D:\DataLoad\test.png')
```

This works fine. It stores the PNG image in the file system no issue.

What I am looking for throughout the documentation is basically the same example but would allow me to store the decoded $b64response as a binary image directly to the database. I cannot find any function to decode base64 to binary and then storing that data in the database.

Now, I know I could inject this file written to disk into the database but I am trying to avoid the issues (like clean-up, multithreading and naming) this would cause.

In case you wonder, the response is like this:

```
<httpclient:response xmlns:httpclient="http://exist-db.org/xquery/httpclient" statusCode="200">
  <httpclient:headers>
    <httpclient:header name="Cache-Control" value="private"/>
    <httpclient:header name="Transfer-Encoding" value="chunked"/>
    <httpclient:header name="Content-Type" value="image/png"/>
    <httpclient:header name="Server" value="Microsoft-IIS/10.0"/>
    <httpclient:header name="X-AspNet-Version" value="4.0.30319"/>
    <httpclient:header name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET"/>
    <httpclient:header name="Date" value="Wed, 26 Jul 2017 21:07:26 GMT"/>
  </httpclient:headers>
<httpclient:body mimetype="image/png" type="binary" encoding="Base64Encoded">iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABfIA .... snipped here
```

So it is all there, I just want to take the httpclient:body/text() and store it as the PNG it represents in the database.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE** I answered my own question with the working solution.

Answer (score 2):

See my commented sample code at https://gist.github.com/joewiz/5938909, which uses the HTTP response body's media-type information as the 4th parameter for the  `xmldb:store()` function to successfully store the binary file in the database. I'm happy to update the code to work if you can point me to an image's URL that the code isn't able to handle.

Comment: I tried what you are doing (essentially util:binary-to-string() on the response and while it saves to the database, the file is corrupt.

Comment: In reading your code, I do not think it answers my question. The content is returned as binary (see above) type="binary" and encoding="Base64Encoded". Thus your code would take the string of the base64 and store it in the database which is exactly what I get if I try to store the response. If I use an editor to examine the file in the database, I see the base64 encoded data and not the binary.

Comment: The key in your comment is that the response is not an image, it is a base64 encoded image.

Comment: See above in question if you wish to evaluate.

Comment: Could you please point me to a publicly reachable URL to a base64 encoded image/file that I (and others, if they get to it first) could use to reproduce your results and test solutions against?

Comment: I added the actual URL. You can pick a PDF from your database (or store one in your database) and run that XQuery. You should pick a one pager as it is only doing an image of the first page,.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but did you actually test my proposed solution before deciding it wouldn't work? I did as you suggested, uploading a PDF to eXist via WebDAV, and ran `local:http-download("http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/test/test.pdf", "/db")` (using the code in my gist), and the resulting PDF at `/db/test.pdf` was a valid PDF. If my proposed solution doesn't work, I'd be grateful for a reproducible test showing it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to cast the response as xs:base64Binary. The following works:

```
xquery version "3.0";
let $testdata := util:binary-doc('/db/data/Customers/assets/eidologo.pdf')
let $url := "http://localhost:4802/Pdf2Img.aspx" 
let $headers := <headers><header name="override-media-type" value="application/octet-stream"/></headers>
let $b64response := httpclient:post(xs:anyURI($url),$testdata,false(),$headers)
return
xmldb:store('/db/data/Customers/assets','test.png', xs:base64Binary($b64response), 'image/png')
```